# How to add I18n in vue 2 after instance of app created?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have internalization in my vue 2 app, and every documentation and each code example I had found says it can be done this way:

```
new Vue({
    store,
    i18n,
    render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

But I need to add i18n after Vue instance created, like so:

```
const app = new Vue({
    store,
    render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
app.i18n = i18n;
```

Is this possible? If yes, how to do it?

Comment: from the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Using-a-Plugin). could you check if that helps?

Comment: @A.Z no it is not working

Comment: This is likely XY problem. Consider addressing it the real problem you try to solve instead of potentially wrong solution.